# Possible to Remove list-style in Napili HTML Editor?

Tags: community, css, html, napili

I have worked with CSS for quite a long time and am familiar with [how to remove the bullets from a list](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1027354/1492485). I've tried to dig out all the tricks I know of, ratcheting up the specificity of my selectors, even resorting to the `!important` flag, moving the attribute to the tag itself in the HTML editor.

```
<ul id="myList">
    <li>Item without a bullet</li>
    <li>Item without a bullet</li>
    <li>Item without a bullet</li>
</ul>
```

When I inspect the elements, it looks like the style is even being applied!

[image: Style definition]

But still, the bullets persist:

[image: Items with bullets]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the builder already hides the `list-style` and then injects `::before` content. This change works:

```
.someWrapper li::before { content: ""; }
```